If $b=\gcd(a,b)q$ then $\gcd(a,q)=1$
By definition of the $\gcd$ we have that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $b$, so there exists a positive integer $q$ such that $b=\gcd(a,b)q$. Is it always true that $\gcd(a,q)=1$? A strategy I found interesting was to rewrite $b=\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,q)m$ for some $m$, then it would be sufficient to prove that the number $\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,q)$ divides both $a$ and $b$ and therefore by maximality, $\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,q)\le\gcd(a,b)$, thus $\gcd(a,q)=1$. It clearly divides $b$, but I'm stuck proving that it divides $a$. Any help is appreciated.

This is true if $b$ is square-free, but not more generally.

Please check for simple counterexamples before posting your questions.

This is not true. Take $b=4$ and $a=2$ and so $\gcd(2,4)=2$ and thus $q=b/(\gcd(a,b)) = 4/2=2$. Then $\gcd(a,q)=\gcd(2,2)=2$.
To generalize: If for some prime $p$ and some integer $e \ge 2$, all three conditions

(a) $p^e$ divides $b$,

(b) $p$ divides $a$, and

(c) $p^e$ does not divide $a$


are all true, then $q:= \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}$ as defined in the OP will share a common divisor with $a$. Indeed, that (a) and (b) are true gives $p$ a divisor of $a$. That (a) and (c) are true gives $p$ a divisor of $q$. And that $p$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $q$ says that $\gcd(a,q)$ is a multiple of $p$.
And indeed, relating this to the example in the first paragraph: can you check for yourself that $a$ and $b$ satisfy (a),(b),(c), with $p=2$ and $e=2$? What about say $a=18$, $b=27$?
